# Use DAX to identify the whether its the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc time that record has been listed in the data set, and label the record with that number

Tags: count, powerbi, sequence, dax

I have a list of live orders.  Each order has a unique ID.  At the month end I run a report which includes the Order ID and the month which the report is run.  I upload this into PowerPivot using Get Data.
The concatenation of Order ID & Monthly Upload is unique to each record, otherwise ID & Month data is repeated in each column.

```
Order ID    Month Uploaded  [Required ie the "Instance"]
10          31/10/19        1
20          31/10/19        1
10          30/11/19        2
30          30/11/19        1
20          31/12/19        2
```

The data isn't sorted into any kind of order.
Every time I upload a set of orders at the end of the month I need the label to update for all the records as the "month upload" could be retrospective.
I want to be able give each record a number label that indicates if its sequentially the 9th, 10th, 100th etc time that the order record has been uploaded.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issue did you encounter with your attempt?

Comment: tried using CALCULATE, FILTER and EARLIER but struggling with it looking at an earlier date rather than an earlier row

Comment: I tried an adaptation of this, which I found elsewhere on the site.




=COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
       'ORDERSTABLE',
       'ORDERSTABLE'[ORDER_ID]=                    
          EARLIER(
             'ORDERTABLE'[ORDER_ID ])
    )
)




I would like it to refer to the count of earlier upload dates associated with the multiple records for a single order ID.

Comment: Not the prettiest solution, but seems to work:  Find the earliest instance of the Upload Date using CALCULATE( MIN(DateField), FILTER(Table, OrderID=EARLIER(OrderID)))).  Then use DATEDIFF to find the number of months between the earliest date the record appeared and the date the current instance of the record appeared

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of a running total.
Note that EARLIER was an early feature of DAX that was largely made redundant when variables were introduced. I'm using variables as it makes the code easier to read.

```
VAR ThisOrderID =  'ORDERSTABLE'[ORDER_ID]
VAR ThisMonthUploaded =  'ORDERSTABLE'[Month Uploaded]

RETURN
CALCULATE
(
    COUNTROWS('ORDERSTABLE'),
    FILTER
    (
     ALL('ORDERSTABLE'),
     'ORDERSTABLE'[ORDER_ID] = ThisOrderID 
        && 'ORDERSTABLE'[Month Uploaded] <= ThisMonthUploaded
    )

)
```